# C# Autocomplete Texbox Click Event

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I use c# winforms visual studio 2010. I have a textbox that have a list as autocomplete data source. Everything is fine except I dont find the event when the autocomplete is clicked. I want on autocomplete row hit do and something else except only fill the textbox with the selected row value. Is it possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No, there is no event nor does Windows itself generate any notification.  You can only see the side-effect, TextChanged.  Background info is in the MSDN article for SHAutoComplete

Answer (score 3):

I ran a quick test this appears to work, don't mind me if this is quite hacky. I created a `UserControl` that inherits from `TextBox`. It monitors the `KeyDown` event, which fires before the `TextChanged` event, toggles a bit to `true` and has the `TextChanged` event review the bit and throw an event (`AutoCompleteUsed`) to alert monitoring classes that the auto-complete functionality was used.

```
public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public delegate void AutoCompleteDelegate();
    public event AutoCompleteDelegate AutoCompleteUsed;
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TextChanged += MyTextBox_TextChanged;
        this.KeyDown += MyTextBox_KeyDown;
    }
    private bool keyPressed = false;
    void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keyPressed = true;
    }

    void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!keyPressed && AutoCompleteUsed != null)
        {
            AutoCompleteUsed();
        }
        keyPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Edit 1: @Hans Passant gave me the answer in his comment, I just gave you a working(ish?) example.